# How to remove line from csv wher some field is missing?

Tags: php, csv

I have a php that outputs such csv:

```
view-source:http://dentopolis.org/scr/pubfeed/csv.php
```

Every row looks like this:

```
Article@Abstract@Authors@Journal@Date@Tags@Pubmed
```

But if some field is missing, somewhere two symbols @@ are together. Example:

```
Article@@Authors@Journal@Date@Tags@Pubmed
```

how to remove such lines?
php?notepad++?regex?

Comment: `sed -i.bak '/@@/d' articles.csv`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your export script is actually generating the CSV with an `@` sign separator instead of the standard comma separator (comma separated values – CSV). What is actually happening is your exporter is finding an empty value for the cell and simply outputting that value as an empty string. If you remove those values it will result in a malformed CSV file unless that empty cell exists in every cell in those columns.

If you are dead set on removing them with regex, here is how to do it in PHP:

```
$pattern = '/\@\@/';
$csv_content = 'big long string here';

echo preg_replace( $pattern, '', $csv_content );
```

This will only remove the double `@` signs and replace them with empty strings. You may want to, instead, replace them with a single `@` sign or something else:

```
echo preg_replace( $pattern, '@', $csv_content );
```

Again, this will likely result in a malformed CSV file.

Comment: some pubmed articled doesn't contain abstract and i don't need those rows in results, that's why i need to remove a whole line.

Answer (score 0):

using notepad++, 
Regex

```
^.*@@.*$
```

1. Go to Mark Tab in search pannel notepad++ check bookmark line, and
   click mark all
2. go to search tab in file menu,select bookmark and choose cut bookmark lines

Done.
[notepad++ snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxyEz.png)